# Could not open linkedIn app with (company profile) url by another android app?

Tags: android, url, linkedin-api, launching-application

i want to open a url from my app, that is "http://www.linkedin.com/company/company-name", If LinkedIn app is installed, need to launch the app. Otherwise, open the url by launch a browser. My code is like below
`

```
public void launchLinkedIn()
 {
        final String urlFb = "linkedin://" + pageId;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlFb));

        final PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        if (list.size() == 0) {
            final String urlBrowser = "http://www.linkedin.com/company/" + pageId;
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlBrowser));
        }
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

`

Now this code is invoke directly to browse even i have linkedin app.. Please help anyone for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a few months ago, but I'm running into the same issue at the moment

After using APKTool to decrypt the app, I've found their deep linking information:
Although the list has various items, the ones that are useful & functional are

```
you
profile/memberId
group/groupId
```

There appears to be no deep linking method for getting to companies, which seems a little strange, but it's how they've built it

I have tried jumping to the activity with setClassName(), but that always crashes as I don't think it's available from the outside

It appears as though the only way to properly get to a company pages is by using linkedin-j

I hope this helps someone