# URLScheme to open linkedIn company profile

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, url-scheme

I'm trying to open a linkedIn company profile using the native app, something like

NSURL *linkedInAppURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://company/nameoridofthecompany"]

user profiles open ok, and I have tried any imaginable kind of combinatios for the deeplink (id,name,company,profile...)

for what I have found
[Could not open linkedIn app with (company profile) url by another android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926588/could-not-open-linkedin-app-with-company-profile-url-by-another-android-app)

looks like (at least a few months ago) there was no support for company links. Do you know if this info is still actual? I have checked linkedIn help and tons of other resources with no luck

Comment: linkedin app is installed on your device?

Comment: Yes, it is. And when I open the NSURL, the app opens, but shows the current user profile, not the company page its supposed to