# How to open Linkedin App with Company Page?

Tags: javascript, android, html, linkedin-api

It is simple HTML Page and my code is below.

```
<a href="linkedin://company/[linkedIncomapanyID]">LinkedIn</a>
```

click on above link in device open LinkedIn app and open company page. This is working fine in IOS devices but not working in Android Devices. Is there any solution for android device? Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happened when you click the Link in Android Devices?

Comment: Just open LinkedIn App only. Not open specific "linkedIncomapanyID" company page. but in iphone  app open with company(linkedIncomapanyID) page.

Comment: this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926588/could-not-open-linkedin-app-with-company-profile-url-by-another-android-app

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101831/how-can-i-open-linkedin-application-from-my-android-app

Comment: It's simple HTML Page not a android app code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution. If the user has the linkedin app the app will be launched else the company profile appear in the browser.

```
String pageId = "your-company-id";
final String urlFb = "linkedin://" + pageId;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlFb));

final PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (list.size() == 0) {
    final String urlBrowser = "http://www.linkedin.com/company/" + pageId;
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlBrowser));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Company Search use :

```
linkedin://profile/company/{company-name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added
 `<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/[companylinkedinURL]">LinkedIn</a>`

If linked in App available than open and redirect to company page.
Working fine in Android Device.